# Converting a CFG into Greibach normal form

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, finite-automata, automata, automata-theory

Do we need to convert a context-free grammar into Chomsky normal form first to convert it into Greibach normal form?

Answer (score 1):

This question might be better suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com/, but there are also plenty of people who can answer it here.

The answer is **no**, you do not need to go through Chomsky Normal form. There is a method in the textbook: Hopcroft, J.E & Ullman J.D. (1969) *Formal Languages and their relation to Automata*, Addison-Wesley, pp.55-57. However, most simple convertions do go through Chomsky Normal Form first. Other techniques are longer and use  *Weak Greibach Normal Form* as an intermediate step.

If you want more details on the method, there are plenty of class notes available on the net; for example [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~massey/Teaching/cs301/RestrictedAccess/Slides/301lecture10.pdf), [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/old511/html/cis51108sl4b.pdf); however, many class notes only show the route through CNF.